# Can I "Order" table "ranks" without locking it ? (don't care for errors)

Tags: mysql, sql-update, locking, query-optimization, window-functions

I have a big table for users with "credits". every few min I want to rank the users by credits.
The problem is that this operation takes time and locks the entire table.
Since I don't care if there is a temporary error in ranks is there a way to perform this function without locking the table ?

```
UPDATE users SET userrank= @r:= (@r+1) ORDER BY credits DESC
```

Comment: How fast are those credits changing? You may be overall faster if you update ranks only when the credits or position actually changes. Do you need the concrete rank value (1,2,3...) e.g. for display or can it be e.g. 1.5 to insert a row between rank 1 and 2?

Comment: Since you are storing the rank in the table, the update operation will always lock all affected records. Consider using a separate rank table if you want to store the ranks. This way the main table does not get locked when you recalculate the rank.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recomment storing the rank in the table itself. This is *derived information*, that can be easily computed on the fly when needed. Maintaining such information is also expensive: everytime the table is modified (either updated, inserted into or deleted from), you potentially need to re-rank all the rows.

An alternative option is to use a view. If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use window functions:

```
create view v_users as
select u.*, rank() over(order by credits) rn
from users u
```

Note that `rank()` assigns the same number to ties.

In earlier versions, one alternative is a correlated subquery (user variables are not supported in views):

```
create view v_users as
select u.*, 1 + (select count(*) from users u1 where u1.credits > u.credits) rn
from users u
```

Comment: @dani - If you try either of these, please report back on how fast they run compared to your original update.

Comment: sure. as soon as I try them I'll report back. wouldn't the view be running again and again every time it is being used ?

Answer (score 1):

How many columns in that table?  Are you doing some queries on that table that need don't need 'rank' and they are being blocked?  If so, consider having a table with just 3 columns -- userid, rank, credits.

That way the blocking query would be working with a smaller table (hence somewhat faster) and not be blocking as many things.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; there may be other tips to help with your problem.